# DFP Tracking Clicks per site (Large Network)

Tags: google-dfp, double-click-advertising

On our DoubleClick For Publishers Small Business Account, we run 50+ ad zone units. These units are all placed carefully and in an organised fashion among 7000+ websites.

The question is, using an account like this, is it possible to access features such as tracking what sites the clicks are coming from in an online dashboard?

We want to know which sites are the ones getting clicks and which aren't.
I've been hearing that we'll need an enterprise account to access more advanced features like tracking the clicks.

Also, if DoubleClick isn't the best option, is there another service which can help?

P.s. We have analytics on these sites and see impressions, but we want to know the actual ad clicks and where they're coming from.

Really appreciate it,

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, will definitely take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DFP macros like Ivo said with utm codes in the creative's code

```
<script>
   var clickTag = %%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%?=utm_source=%%SITE%%-%ecid!
</script>
```

Where:

%%SITE%% is the site

%ecid! is the Creative ID. It is an Expand Macro.

And track the utm codes in Google Analytics.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Is this possible without the premium feature?
Regards.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can check the macros here https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/2376981?hl=en

Comment: I've setup a creative that looks like this <a target="_blank" href=" %%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%?=utm_source=%%SITE%%-%ecid!">
    <img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/8346991038167556883">
</a>

I had to statically add the image as well, as you can see. Where do I now see this information? I was unclear how to track it within google analytics. Thanks, Noy.

Comment: Also, is it possible to call a function from my original code from within that DFP code snippet? e.g. document.getElementById('somebutton').click();

Comment: You can track it in GA > Acquisition > Campaigns.

Comment: Been looking in there recently, it's currently all empty. Even after I've made the UTM tags on the Banner

Answer (score 0):

What creatives (banners) are using? There is a Site Macro that can be used in the creative, so it could provide that information:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2376981?hl=en

Comment: I've made a new order -> new line item and within a line item I have 1 creative. Sometimes these creatives run across 3000+ sites. I need to know which sites are the ones that are being clicked.

Comment: May I also mention that I don't have premium, We are using DFP for small business.

Comment: The site macro usually helps, but it really depends on the creative code.